# Installing mDNS resolver in Bash on Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, avahi, mdns

I am trying to connect to a PC over mDNS from a Bash script running on Windows. While I am able to ping the PC through its mDNS `.local` address in CMD, doing the same in an Ubuntu/Bash window fails due to a hostname resolution issue.

When I try to install `avahi-daemon`, it seems to fail to start the service, and as a result I can't resolve mDNS names.

```
$ sudo apt-get install avahi-daemon
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libfreetype6 os-prober
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libavahi-core7 libdaemon0 libnss-mdns
Suggested packages:
  avahi-autoipd
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  avahi-daemon libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libavahi-core7 libdaemon0
  libnss-mdns
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 220 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,094 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libavahi-common-data amd64 0.6.31-4ubuntu1 [21.2 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libavahi-common3 amd64 0.6.31-4ubuntu1 [21.7 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libavahi-core7 amd64 0.6.31-4ubuntu1 [80.9 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libdaemon0 amd64 0.14-2ubuntu1 [16.4 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main avahi-daemon amd64 0.6.31-4ubuntu1 [58.7 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libnss-mdns amd64 0.10-6 [21.4 kB]
Fetched 220 kB in 1s (159 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libavahi-common-data:amd64.
(Reading database ... 24998 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libavahi-common-data_0.6.31-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libavahi-common-data:amd64 (0.6.31-4ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libavahi-common3:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libavahi-common3_0.6.31-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libavahi-common3:amd64 (0.6.31-4ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libavahi-core7:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libavahi-core7_0.6.31-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libavahi-core7:amd64 (0.6.31-4ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdaemon0.
Preparing to unpack .../libdaemon0_0.14-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdaemon0 (0.14-2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package avahi-daemon.
Preparing to unpack .../avahi-daemon_0.6.31-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking avahi-daemon (0.6.31-4ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnss-mdns:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libnss-mdns_0.10-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnss-mdns:amd64 (0.10-6) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libavahi-common-data:amd64 (0.6.31-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libavahi-common3:amd64 (0.6.31-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libavahi-core7:amd64 (0.6.31-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libdaemon0 (0.14-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up avahi-daemon (0.6.31-4ubuntu1) ...
runlevel:/var/run/utmp: No such file or directory
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of force-reload.
runlevel:/var/run/utmp: No such file or directory
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Setting up libnss-mdns:amd64 (0.10-6) ...
First installation detected...
Checking NSS setup...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.7) ...
$ ping my-other-pc.local
ping: unknown host my-other-pc.local
```

What do I need to do to be able to resolve mDNS names? Is there an alternative to installing Avahi that works, or is there something else that I need to do to make this package function?

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

1. Install the `libnss-mdns` package which will change your system's resolver to query `.local.` domains via mDNS. Note that most builds of this do not honour `local` on the resolver search path (see the comments on [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/377830/7408)) so you will need to look up `MacbookPro.local` rather than just `MacbookPro`.
2. Install the `avahi-utils` package and use the `avahi-resolve` program to do the lookups. You may also find the other tools in this package to be an easier way of looking up services and the like.